# Multiple fields with same name in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have two *Title* fields:

```
<include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
  <Title>{150F559C-5B28-4C85-8A14-23345334B447}</Title>
  <Title>{A736D876-9072-45FC-B42A-A8629F141604}</Title>
</include>
```

I need both to be indexed, but only the first *Title* field is being indexed.

Is there a way, we can merge both *Title* fields into one *Title* field?

Comment: you can use copy field and push both the fields in single field.

Comment: any example how to do it @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/copying-fields.html

Comment: Is your `Title` field in Solr set to being multiValued? If that's the case, Solr should handle it automagically, but I'm not sure if sitecore would export it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the following Solr config to explicitly specify field Ids to be added to the Solr index:

```
<include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
  <fieldId>{150F559C-5B28-4C85-8A14-23345334B447}</fieldId>
  <fieldId>{A736D876-9072-45FC-B42A-A8629F141604}</fieldId>
</include>
```